# Custom action cannot find installed files

Tags: wix, custom-action

I have made a custom action to update a xml file which is installed. I'm passing the path of the file to the custom action with `CustomActionData`. This works fine, but when I try to open the xml file in the custom action the action is looking in the wrong directory.

```
<CustomAction Id="UpdateConfigCustomAction" BinaryKey="CustomActionsDLL" 
                  DllEntry="UpdateConfigFileAction" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="SetPropertiesCustomAction" Before="UpdateConfigCustomAction" />
      <Custom Action="UpdateConfigCustomAction" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

For example the path of the xml file is: `C:\Program Files(x86)\MyProgram\file.xml` but the action is looking at `C:\Windows\Installer\****.TMP\C:\Program Files(x86)\MyProgram\file.xml`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How are you resolving the path?  I'm guessing that your DLL is working this out based on the current path.  Have you tried setting the `Directory` or `Property`/`Value` attributes to the install directory?